# Create a function which gives us another function

Tags: c#, .net, func

As input to another program I am using I need to input a delegate of the form:

```
Func<double, double, double>.
```

I want the function to be sent in to be

> F(a,b)=a+b*c+d

where `c` and `d` are known constants known at runtime.

So what I need is some method which takes the values c and d, and then gives me a function `F(a,b)`. What I think I need to do is to first create the method:

```
double der(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
   return a + b * c + d;
}
```

And from this method I have to do something with delegates in order to get my function. Do you see how to solve this problem?

Comment: Be careful that `Func<double,double,double>` does not describe a function that takes 3 `double` as parameters, but rather a function that takes 2 `double` and returns a `double`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the return value as your expected Func:

```
Func<double, double, double> MakeFunction(double c, double d)
```

now you can use a lambda expression to construct the function that you desire:

```
return (a,b) => a + b * c + d;
```

Explanation:

the `(a,b)` denote the input parameters for your function. As the designated return value in the method signature specifies that this will be 2 parameters of type `double`. the part after the `=>` denotes the calculation that will be performed.

Now you can use it in the following way:

```
var myFunc = MakeFunction(3, 4);    
Console.WriteLine(myFunc(1, 2));
```

> TEST Code:

```
double a = 1;
double b = 2;
double c = 3;
double d = 4;
var myFunc = MakeFunction(c, d);
Console.WriteLine("Func: " + myFunc(a, b));
Console.WriteLine("Direct test: "a + b * c + d);
```

> OUTPUT:
>   Func: 11
>   Direct test:  11

Comment: Thank you very much, I have to learn how to use lambda expressions.

Comment: @user394334 you're welcome. have fun, it is a very interesting topic